# Variable not work by using shell_exec for background execution

Tags: php, shell

I used shell_exec command to get parallel execution of php script like this :

```
    shell_exec("echo \"<?php require_once 'path/to/function.php'; DBTest::function2('f2-2');?>\" | php >/dev/null 2>&1 & ");
```

This work correct , put in this way I can't use variable,like this:

```
    shell_exec("echo \"<?php require_once 'path/to/function.php'; $s =25 ; DBTest::function2('f2-2');?>\" | php >/dev/null 2>&1 & ");
```

it's not execute!
Can help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your string is in double quotes, your $ gets expanded, before it is passed to shell_exec. See [string parsing](http://www.php.net:80/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).

Escape with a backslash :

```
 shell_exec("echo \"<?php require_once 'path/to/function.php'; \$s =25 ; DBTest::function2('f2-2');?>\" | php >/dev/null 2>&1 & ");
```

In the shell, $ is also a special character. I'm not sure if you have to escape it a second time for the shell.